# Issue in mapping a new table data to an existing table

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a parent table like below

```
CREATE TABLE "Tablename"
(
  "column1" integer,
  "column2" integer NOT NULL, 
  "column3" text, 
  "column4" integer,
  "column5" text, 
  "column6" integer,
  CONSTRAINT "Tablename_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("column1"),
  CONSTRAINT uk_t1 UNIQUE ("column2")
);
```

so in the above table, `column2` is `Unique`&`Not Null` which means primary key??
I am trying to assign `column2` as `Foreign Key` in another table but I get the error like below

> ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "Tablename"
>   SQL state: 42830

Note If I assign the `column2` as `Primary Key` directly in the parent table, then I am able to assign it as a `Foreign Key` in the child table. Here I can't do that. I need help for the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked from `psql`.  Are you just having a syntax problem?

```
CREATE TABLE foo 
 (column2 integer not null,
  FOREIGN KEY (column2) REFERENCES "Tablename"(column2)
);
```